# My SSL certificate secure padlock appears for 1 second on homepage and disappears. It works in the admin control panel

Tags: security, ssl, web, certificate

Can anyone tell me why the SSL secure padlock appears for 1 second then disapears?
https://www.beckyliu.com/
It appears in my admin control panel just not the main site.
I tried to change all the resource locations to https://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few URLs which do not use HTTPS, few URLs from your home page are:

- http://i68.tinypic.com/25hhe8y.gif
- http://www.beckyliu.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cursor.png
- http://www.beckyliu.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cursor-mouse.png

Kindly make sure all contents of your page use HTTPS, that will resolve your issue.

Comment: Please refer following blog to enable it in WordPress:
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/

Comment: My pleasure, good to see that your issues is now resolved @RuilkGold